# Автозапуск телеграмм бота на сервере

Tags: python, linux

Коллеги, добрый день!
Я разместил телеграмм бота на сервере на Линукс.
После нескольких часов простоя, бот отключается.
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать автозапуск на сервере?
Или какой то есть другой способ поправить проблему?
Заранее спасибо за помощь?

Comment: Что значит «отключается»? Кто и почему его отключает?

Comment: Про автозапуск в Linux на сайте уже и так [есть куча вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux%2b%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba?tab=Votes)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Коллеги, спасибо за помощь, нашел ответ по ссылке)

Comment: В таком случае закрывайте вопрос